# async call does not wait to finish for firebase function

Tags: firebase, async-await, request, google-cloud-functions, request-promise

I am making a download content call using request in my firebase function but it does not wait to finish and function finishes execution. The code looks like below:

```
exports.my_handler = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    console.log("my_handler starts")
     var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
    await request.get(req.query.downloadUrl, async function (error:any, response:any, body:any) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {                
            const data = new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
            console.log(data);
            const fileName = (new Date().getTime()).toString()
            console.log(":::::::CODE does not reach here always")
        }
    });


    res.status(200).send("done")
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that request.get() returns a promise?  If it doesn't, await won't help you in this case.

Comment: I m not sure and that is likely the problem.  How to solve? Please advice

Comment: I think it's best to first find the API documentation for the library you're using and see what it actually does - don't guess about it.  If you're using a callback based API, then you'll need to send the response in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

i used a promise return to solve it like below

```
async function downloadContentFromUrl(downloadUrl:string) {
    console.log("start of downloadContentFromUrl")
    // Return new promise 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Do async job
        var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
        request.get(downloadUrl, async function (err:any, resp:any, body:any) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(new Buffer(body).toString('base64'));
            }
        })
    })
}
```